# Kotlin shorthand for implementing a functional interface with annotations

Tags: kotlin, functional-interface

In Kotlin, is there a way to define an annotated class implementing a functional interface that is shorter than the following:

```
@Foo
class Bar : Runnable {
    override fun run() = ...
}
```

I'm hoping to find something like the following made-up syntax:

```
@Foo
fun Bar : Runnable () = ...
```

Due to interoperability reasons, I must end up with a class annotated with `@Foo` implementing `Runnable` or an instance of a class annotated with `@Foo` implementing `Runnable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the shortest syntax would be this:

```
@Foo object: Runnable {
    override fun run() {}
}
```

If you [annotate lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#lambdas), the annotation will be applied on the `invoke` function rather than the implemented class.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't been able to find anything shorter myself either.